# GraphQL StaticQuery of an image in Gatsby broken

Tags: graphql, gatsby, netlify-cms

In my copy of [Gatsby Netlify CMS starter kit](https://github.com/thomaswang/gatsby-personal-starter-blog) I've made a reusable header.js component (`components/header.js`) which shows my site logo and nav. Problem is my logo image won't show up, with error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of null` which I interpret to mean I'm querying the image path incorrectly.

I have my logo.gif image in the same components folder, and I also added it to `content/assets`. My static query, which I gather is specifically for querying in components, looks like this:

```
<StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query LogoQuery {
          logo: file(absolutePath: { regex: "logo.gif" }) {
            childImageSharp {
              fixed(width: 500, height: 350) {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `}
      render={data => (
    ....
    <Img fixed={data.logo.childImageSharp.fixed} alt="Home" />
    ....
```

I also tried relativePath, to no avail:

```
query LogoQuery {
  logo: file(relativePath: { eq: "assets/logo.gif" }) {
    childImageSharp {
      fixed(width: 500, height: 350) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`}

Guessing I want absolute path since header will be in post subfolders, doesn't say anything about the 2 options [in the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-query/) though. Regardless, neither seem to work. Any guidance greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ha it turns out that this just doesn't work for gifs... only jpgs and pngs. Strange!